# optimizing Spring Boot JPA query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Jpa. I have a List list which has about 10000-50000 client objects in it.

I'm iterating through this list and querying each client if he has made any purchases like this:

```
List<TransactRepViewModel> temporalList = transactRepViewRepository
        .findByClientIdAndClDateBetween(clieTabModel.getClientId(),
                reportInterval.getStartDate(),
                reportInterval.getEndDate());
```

**TransactRepViewRepository.class** method looks like this:

```
List<TransactRepViewModel> findByClientIdAndClDateBetween(
        String clientId, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws DataAccessException;
```

I would really like to improve my search time, since iterating through such amount of clients takes quite some time. Are there any technique I could use?

Comment: Write a "findAll" query?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: write a new method on your JPA repository. This method could be like: findAllByStartDateEndDate. This link might help: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: This will not improve search time.

Comment: Where does this huge list of clients come from? If it comes from another query, then you should use a single query with a join. If it comes from somewhere else, consider using an `in` clause to pass many client IDs at once. But beware that most databases limit the number of values inside the in clause, and/or the length of the query. Oracle for example has a limit of 1000. Still, that would reduce the number of queries from 50000 to 50.

Comment: "This will not improve search time" yes it will. Each individual DB call incurs an IO overhead. The less individual queries you make the faster it will, usually, be

Comment: @JBNizet agree: use "join" or "in" if you can in one query

Comment: Can you upload your domain classes referenced?  I can help with this but I don't understand the relationships/entities involved.

Comment: This list comes from a table of clients.

Comment: @JoeEssey you mean the pojos?

Comment: Then use a query with a join. Instead of `select c from Client c where blaba` followed by many `select t from Transact t where t.client.id = ... and foobar`, use a single query looking like `select t from Transact join t.client c where blabla and foobar`

Comment: @JBNizet but that isn't that a per client query also and doesn't get rid of iteration?

Comment: No. It uses a single query with a where clause selecting the right clients, and the right Transacts for those clients.

Comment: but the right clients is a list... so i don't get it how that would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to make a concrete recommendation without knowing a lot more about what you're trying to do, but generally:

- Do one large query, so, for example, create a repository method that finds **all** purchases between the dates that you are interested in, and make sure that the result includes the client id. Then match up the results with clients in Java code after you get the results back. This avoids the overhead of doing potentially thousands of database queries. You might want to "order by" the client id and purchase date.
- Make sure that you have proper indexes on the table(s) involved, and verify that when jpa executes it's query, the database uses the indexes. A table scan would probably kill performance.